# Angular google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs

Hi i am currently working on angular Google maps https://github.com/dylanfprice/angular-gm
i am facing difficulties in setting the bounds and map center

```
 <gm-map gm-map-id="'infoWindows'" gm-center="options.map.center"  gm-zoom="options.map.zoom" gm-bounds="bounds" gm-map-options="options.map" class="map">
            <gm-markers gm-objects="clinics"
                        gm-get-lat-lng="{ lat: object.practice.latitude, lng: object.practice.longitude }"
                        gm-get-marker-options="{ title: object.practice.name }"
                        gm-on-click="clk = object; infoWindow.open(marker.getMap(), marker);">
            </gm-markers>
          </gm-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your map is already loaded.

therefor it is highly recommended to use promises.

```
  var gmapPromise = angulargmContainer.getMapPromise('<mapId>');

  gmapPromise.then(function(gmap) {
    $scope.myGoogleMap = gmap;
  });
```

In your case  would be 'infoWindows'.

as there is to less context in your question, i can't really give you an answer what is wrong with your particular code but i'll give you some snippet which is always useful:

```
$scope.updateGoogleMap = function(map, options) {
    // triggers a resize of the map and sets the correct center position
    // requires a google map object and a google maps mapOptions object
    $timeout(function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setOptions(options);
    });
};
```

a Google Maps mapOption object looks like this:

```
{
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.123, 10.123),
 zoom: 3,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
```

as ng-hide/show lead to some google maps resize misbehaviour, you might wanna call this when toggling views.

**by the way, if your are using the gm-map-options tag with a valid [google.maps.MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de#MapOptions), you don't need the the extra 'gm-bounds', 'gm-zoom' or 'gm-center' arguments